# Chrome: How to hide 1 particular tab in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

A google search gives number of methods to hide **ALL** tabs in chrome , but I want to hide **1** particular tab / change the display name of that tab.

Reason: I have an online music playing website open, which keeps showing tracks in the tab name and I just want to remove it from view of my work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right-click → select "Pin tab". Pinned tabs don't show their display name at all. *(Though they also move to the very beginning of your tab bar.)*

[image: Example of a pinned tab in Chrome]

[image: Example of a pinned tab in Firefox]

Alternatively: Drag / "tear" the tab off into its own window, then minimize that window (or even move it to another workspace), or just hide it behind your work windows.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the above solution

You can use [blurscreen.app](https://blurscreen.app) to hide 1 tab as you asked for, it is a desktop app so will work for chrome, edge, or any other browser you use.

you can hide anything with this

here is how to hide 1 particular tab in chrome
[image]

Ps: I am the creator of the app

Comment: If you're going to promote your own apps here (paid ones even more so), at the very minimum you have to disclose your affiliation.